# CodeMirror is not hignlighting XML

Tags: javascript, xml, codemirror

I want to highlight xml code inside textarea using CodeMirror but for some reason it fails. What's the reason?

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/lib/codemirror.css"/>
    <textarea rows="25" class="field span8" id="xmlRequestTextarea" name="xmlRequestValue" class="form-control" ng-model="xmlRequestValue" required></textarea>

    <script>
        var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("xmlRequestTextarea"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "htmlmixed"
        });
        myCodeMirror.htmlMode(false);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the `"htmlmixed"` mode, but you didn't load it (or its dependencies, the javascript and css modes, as well as the xml mode you loaded). If you don't need inline javascript and css to be highlighted, you can set the `mode` option to `text/html` after loading the xml mode, and you'll get HTML highlighting.

Also, the `htmlMode` method is definitely not a thing.